# C code function calling not working

Tags: c, arrays, function, for-loop, recursion

Ok I need to write two functions iterative and recursive to count negative elements in an array and then I need to build main. I was only able to write the recursive  function but I cannot call it from main, it is an error somewhere. Can someone help me out solve it and help me with the iterative method?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int vektor[100];
    int i, madhesia;

    /* Input size of array */
    printf("Madhesia e vektorit: ");
    scanf("%d", &madhesia);

    /* Input array elements */
    printf("Elementet: ");
    for (i = 0; i < madhesia; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vektor[i]);
    }

    int ret = numero(vektor, madhesia);
    printf("\nTotal negative elements in array = %d", ret);

    return 0;
}

int numero(array, size)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: `int numero(array,size)` -->  `int numero(int* array, int size)`

Comment: Please read ["Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: `main()` --> `int main()`

Comment: and... put the code for the function before `main` (or make a forward declaration)

Comment: It is the iterative function you have written (not the recursive as the question states).

Comment: and... always check the value returned by `scanf`

Comment: What have you tried to do for the recursive function? Show what you got so far and maybe we can help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

A working piece of code is this.You really need to take a look at pointers and the way they work.
Here you can see that I have a pointer ->pointing-< at the start of the array , so by passing the starting address of the array , and the length of the array , your functions knows what it is needed to be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int numero(int* array, int size);
int* recursive_count(int* array, int size , int* counter );


int main()
{
    int vektor[100];
    int* vekt_ptr = &vektor[0];
    int i, madhesia;
    int counter;
    counter=0;

    /* Input size of array */
    printf("Madhesia e vektorit: ");
    scanf("%d", &madhesia);

    /* Input array elements */
    printf("Elementet: ");
    for (i = 0; i < madhesia; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vektor[i]);
    }

    //int ret = numero(vekt_ptr, madhesia);
    recursive_count(vekt_ptr, madhesia , &counter );
    int ret = counter;
    printf("\nTotal negative elements in array = %d", ret);

    return 0;
}

int numero(int* array, int size)
{
    int count = 0;
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int* recursive_count(int* array, int size , int* counter )
{
    size--;
    if(array[size] < 0 )
    {
        (*counter)++;
    }
    if(size==0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    return recursive_count(array++, size , counter );
}
```

Let's assume that you want to create dynamically an array of X length.
The compiler is going to have some memory for your array , depending on the length.
You initialize your array , lets say [2][45][1][-5][99]
When you call the function you have to pass where this is stored in memory.
int* vekt_ptr = &vektor[0]; -s going to give as something like 0x56c2e0. 
This number is the address of your array , which is the address of the starting point of the array.This is equal with the address of first byte.
So when your function starts , it knows where your array starts and how long it is.

Comment: 1) Some description of your change (i.e. what and why) would improve your answer and 2) `vekt_ptr` is not need at all - just use `vektor` directly

Comment: Yes descriptions and explanations are updating.Indeed int* ptr is not needed but I use it to make clear to him what he has to do.

Comment: you could pass &vektor[0] directly - or vektor which is the same as &vektor[0].

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis I have to disagree that using `vekt_ptr` makes anything more clear. To me it is just adding confusion. OP seemed to be well aware that `vektor` could be passed directly so why confuse OP by introducing an unnecessary variable.

Comment: thisis the recursive method right? What do I need to change to make it iterative?

Comment: This is the iterative method actually, a recursive method is a method calling itself from within itself.

Comment: Could you help me out please?

Comment: Try the code I posted , it's working.Calm down and try it , then ask me what you need.Don't forget to press V :)

Comment: Yeah I tried it but its the iterative one. I need recursive

Comment: Now it has a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Any function used in a program shall be declared before its usage.

This function declaration of the function definition

```
int numero(array, size)
{
    // ...
}
```

is invalid because the types of the parameters `array` and `size` are undefined.

For the size of an array and for the count of elements it is better to use an unsigned integer type like for example `size_t` or at least `unsigned int`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N   100

size_t iterative_numero( const int array[], size_t size );
size_t recursive_numero( const int array[], size_t size );

int main( void )
{
    int vektor[N];
    size_t madhesia = 0;

    /* Input size of array */
    printf("Madhesia e vektorit: ");
    scanf("%zu", &madhesia);

    if ( N < madhesia ) madhesia = N;

    /* Input array elements */
    printf("Elementet: ");
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < madhesia; i++ )
    {
        scanf( "%d", &vektor[i] );
    }

    size_t ret = iterative_numero(vektor, madhesia );
    printf("\nTotal negative elements in array = %zu\n", ret);
    ret = recursive_numero(vektor, madhesia );
    printf("Total negative elements in array = %zu\n", ret);

    return 0;
}

size_t iterative_numero( const int array[], size_t size )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if ( array[i] < 0 )
        {
            count++;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

size_t recursive_numero( const int array[], size_t size )
{
    return size == 0 ? 0 : ( array[0] < 0 ) + recursive_numero( array + 1, size - 1 );
}
```

the program output might look like

```
Madhesia e vektorit: 10
Elementet: 0 -1 2 -3 4 -5 6 -7 8 -9

Total negative elements in array = 5
Total negative elements in array = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all what you did is the iterative method, not recursive. Here I have called a recursive function from the main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int vektor[100];
int i, madhesia;

/* Input size of array */
printf("Madhesia e vektorit: ");
scanf("%d", &madhesia);

/* Input array elements */
printf("\nElementet: ");
for (i = 0; i < madhesia; i++)
{
    scanf("%d", &vektor[i]);
}

printf("\nno of elements:%d",madhesia);
printf("\n");

for (i = 0; i < madhesia; i++)
{
    printf("%d", vektor[i]);
}
printf("\n");
i=0;

int ret = numero(vektor,madhesia,0,i);
printf("\nTotal negative elements in array = %d", ret);

return 0;
}

int numero(int array[],int size,int count,int j)
{
 if (j<=size-1)
{
if(array[j]<0)
    {
        count++;
        j++;
        numero(array,size,count,j);
}

else
{
   j++;
   numero(array,size,count,j);

 }
 }

return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put function prototype of numero() before main() to be able to call it. Declare function parameters with type:

```
int numero(int array[], int size);

int main() {
...
```

Comment: I would also add: `int numero(array, size)` --> `int numero(int* array, int size)`

Answer (score 0):

Some possible implementations:

```
int iterativeCountNegativeIntegers (int *array, int size)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++ i)
         if (array[i] < 0)
             result += 1;
    return result;
}

int recursiveCountNegativeIntegers (int *array, int size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return 0;

    int partial = *array < 0;
    return partial + recursiveCountNegativeIntegers(array+1, size-1);
}
```

The same, condensed:

```
int iterativeCountNegativeIntegers_1 (int *array, int size)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (--size >= 0)
         result += *array++ < 0;
    return result;
}


int recursiveCountNegativeIntegers_1 (int *array, int size)
{
    return (size == 0) ? 0
      : (*array < 0) + recursiveCountNegativeIntegers_1(array+1, size-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int numero(int *, int);    //Function Prototype (1)

int main()      //Return Type (2)
{
    int vektor[100];
    int i, madhesia;
    printf("Madhesia e vektorit: ");
    scanf("%d", &madhesia);
    printf("Elementet: ");
    for (i = 0; i < madhesia; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &vektor[i]);
    }
    int ret = numero(vektor, madhesia);
    printf("\nTotal negative elements in array = %d", ret);
    return 0;
}

int numero(int* array,int size)        //Parameters Data Type (3)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] < 0)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Errors:

1. You have declared the function after "main()" so the program doesn't know that there is a function, so you have to give the function prototype before "main()" so that the program knows there is function ahead.
2. You missed writing the return type of "main()" which is integer.
3. In the function declaration you forgot to write the data type of the parameters.

NOTE: The array is always passed by reference so it has to taken in an integer pointer instead of a normal integer.